# Creating web service file, only code file is created

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, vb.net-2010

I feel very noobish asking this but I can't find an answer.

I using Visual Studio 2010 and attempting to create a simple XML web service. I created a web service project using .NET 3.5. In my solution explorer I see the file

```
mywebservice.asmx
```

however if I double click on it I get the code behind

```
mywebservice.asmx.vb
```

I'm not seeing anywhere(cannot expand mywebservice.asmx in solution explorer) that I can see the front end file. In the book I am following it says there should be a file created with the @websercive directive, something like this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/MyClass.vb" Class="MyClass" %>
```

but I'm just not seeing it. I find it strange that the only file I see in solution explorer is the .asmx file but when I open it I see .asmx.vb .

Could anyone tell me what is going on here? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the file in Solution Explorer and select View Markup.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the code file and press F7.  That should take you to the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the app_code folder?